# Reinstalled Ubuntu on my Win10&Xubuntu Dual boot PC, now cannot boot into windows 10 - How to fix it?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, windows-10

Ok, so I had a dual boot running on my laptop with Windows 10 and Xubuntu. Everything worked fine but I wanted to use Ubuntu instead. So from Windows, I deleted the partition where Xubuntu was installed, created a live USB for Ubuntu and restarted my PC to install Ubuntu (18.04.3)

**Note:** Now I believe this is not the proper way to reinstall Linux distros on a dual boot PC but this is the method I had used in the past to install or reinstall other Linux distros and it worked completely fine.

So after booting from the live USB, I proceeded to install Ubuntu and this time it didn't give me the option to *Install Ubuntu alongside Windows* which was the option I selected during previous re-installation. Not finding that option I selected the custom partition option. And installed Ubuntu that way but without touching the Windows partitions.

After the installation was complete, I couldn't boot into any of the OS, but by following some steps and reinstalling my GRUB bootloader, I was able to boot into Ubuntu. But now while booting, it doesn't show the GRUB menu automatically, I tried pressing Shift while booting and it did show the GRUB menu but Windows was not available there.

So now I am stuck here and I can't get into Windows, how do I fix it?

Comment: which ubuntu version did you try to reinstall? In my case, I know that 14.04 version didn't recognize Windows 8.1 (that was 5 years ago), so I must install it carefully using custom options

Comment: Its the latest version, Ubuntu 18.04.3